# Accessing Webpage Elements Using Watir for gmail signup

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am working on sample gmail login application on the gmail login page.

When I clicked on  create an account link a new page  display,In this  page I want  to access the Month(Under Birthday section).

I tried with the div element it gives an error can you please help me out.?

Comment: I will give you code.. after some time. In the mean time if anyone give you,, then use it.. :)

Comment: hey when can i expect that

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this , it will work fine**

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

ie=Watir::Browser.new :firefox

ie.goto "https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dgoog%26oq%3Dgoog%26aqs%3Dchrome..69i57j69i60l5.807j0%26sourceid%3Dchrome%26espv%3D210%26es_sm%3D93%26ie%3DUTF-8&hl=en"

ie.div(:text,"Month").click

#here you can put your month you want to select
ie.div(:text,"March").click


#select date here
ie.text_field(:id, "BirthDay").set "11"

#select year here
ie.text_field(:id, "BirthYear").set "1992"
```

Comment: hey prashanth can u please tell me how  to navigate the browser using watir, till now i have been doing these through watir-webdriver........

Comment: i mean opening the browser from command prompt like e.goto 'www.gmail.com' i have been doing these using watir-webdriver i want to open the site using watir in IE

Comment: Please download the IEDriverServer from "http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list" and place the executable on your PATH.It mean you should downlaod the extension from this link on the basic of your window.and then set path of this in environment variable.

Comment: yaa exactly these is wat i see when i execute that the statement, ok fine i will do that can u please tell me how to do it bby default like if we 'require watir ' the browser will be opened in IE by default can u plaese tell how  to do that

Comment: C:\Users\Farooq>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'watir'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- watir/loaderfromD:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'fromD:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_reuire.rb:36:in `require'fromD:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commonwatir-4.0.0/lib/watir.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:i
n`require'fromD:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in`rescueinrequire'fromD:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:

Comment: you should use require 'watir-webdriver' and delete  require 'watir' from your code.

Comment: hey these is not working in IE 8 "ie.div(:text,"Month").click

Comment: hey these is not working in IE 8 "ie.div(:text,"Month").click I am using ruby 1.8.7 version IE 8 version windows 7

Comment: hey prashanth can u please help regarding the following issue "hey these is not working in IE 8 "ie.div(:text,"Month").click I am using ruby 1.8.7 version IE 8 version windows 7"

Comment: why are you using ruby  1.8.7?

Comment: you can use more latest version of ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I think you was confused where to click to select month.Actually when you will click on the div on the basis of id,javascript runs.

```
ie.div(:text,"Month").click
//here you can place any month with correct name
ie.div(:text,"March").click
```

Comment: hey its working fine in IE 10 but not in IE 8 with ruby 1.8.7 version,can u please help me out

Comment: hey its working fine with ie 10 but not in ie 8 can u please help me out